# Date poll with range selection and intersection detection

Tags: polls

I wonder if there is an online tool, to plan an event based on invitees availability over date ranges. Everyone fills one or more date ranges on a calendar and it displays intersection of availabilities.

Because each time I want to poll a date (on framadate, or directly in whatsapp, messenger, discord) I must enumerate all dates of a week, or a month and people are often available at dates which have not been enumerated.

Thanks